# What package provides the "wl" kernel module?

Tags: modules

I've found a bug with the "wl" kernel module, and I'd like to report a bug. I'm not sure what package provides it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=824931), it seems that Broadcom directly provides the `wl` module. Their code page for it is here: http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php.

It looks like they want you to email support requests to the address provided on that page.